# Dynamic array resize function problems

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

NOTE: I am aware that it would be easier to just use the STL Vector, however, for a programming class that I'm in, we are required to write our own dynamic array template class because our professor apparently enjoys making us reinvent the wheel.

Anyway, I made a resize function for my dynamic array template class that goes as follows. Note that the private member variables are T* arr, unsigned used, and unsigned cap.

```
template <class T>
void darray<T>::resize(unsigned size)
{
    if (size > cap)
    {
        T* temp_arr = new T[size];

        for (int count = 0; count < used; ++count)
            temp_arr[count] = arr[count];

        for (int count = used; count < size; ++count)
            temp_arr[count] = T();

        delete []arr;
        arr = temp_arr;
        cap = size;
        used = size;
    }

    if (size < cap)
    {
        used = size;
    }
}
```

Whenever I use this function to increase the size of the array, it will work the first time I need to use it, but after that, Visual Studios will trigger a breakpoint at line 14 (`delete[] arr`), and if I continue past the breaks, I eventually get `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)` assertion failure. What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

constructor:

```
template <class T>
darray<T>::darray()
{
used = 0;
cap = 64;

arr = new T[cap];

for (int count = 0; count < cap; ++count)
    arr[count] = T();
```

}

assignment operator:

```
template <class T>
darray<T>& darray<T>::operator= (const darray& right_operand)
{
    delete[] arr;
    arr = new T[right_operand.capacity()];
    used = right_operand.size();
    cap = right_operand.capacity();

    for (int count = 0; count < used; ++count)
        arr[count] = right_operand[count];
    return *this;
}
```

destructor:

```
template <class T>
darray<T>::~darray()
{
    delete[] arr;
}
```

There's been some requests for the push_back function, so here's that as well:

```
template <class T>
void darray<T>::push_back(const T& input)
{
    if ((used + 1) > cap)
    {
    resize(cap * 2);
    arr[used + 1] = input;
    ++used;
    }

    else
    {
        arr[used] = input;
        ++used;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a ; in the second for

Comment: You have a memory leak if you expand -> contract -> expand again due to unreleased memory of the objects themselves

Comment: Seems the professor made a good choice, as it's apparently not trivial to create a working implementation ;)

Comment: If you know vector already, why don't you have a look at it's source code to see how it's done? It's going to be hard to come up with a better implementation.. A+++ all the way :P

Comment: shouldnt the `T();` be `new T()` ?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this piece of code. Did you initialize arr to be nullptr in the constructor?

Comment: Does your class follow the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722) properly? (One good reason for reinventing this particular wheel is to learn the complications of resource management and copy/move semantics. You can usually use library classes to take care of these details for you, but it's important to understand how they work.)

Comment: I didn't initialize it to be nullptr, but I did initialize it to be an array of 64 empty values and set cap to 64

Comment: @KarthikT No. How? Those are of different types.

Comment: @user3559437 Can we see the constructor that was used for the object in question?

Comment: Yes, I followed the Rule of Three, I could post the implementations of those as well if it would help

Comment: Just posted the implementations

Comment: Does it crash for trivial instantiations, such as `int`? Also, do you do anything inbetween the resizings?

Comment: It does crash for int, that's what I'm currently using it for. The only thing that I'm doing in between the resizeings is using a simple push_back, which just gives a value to the appropriate location, increments used, and calls resize if used is > cap

Comment: You should post your `push_back` code as well. The error might be there although it it is reported on deletion.

Comment: Could you post the full code? Also why do you set used to equal size after a resize?

Comment: You're right about the used being set to size, I changed that in my actual code. I don't think I can post my entire code here, but I did include puch_back

Comment: Actually, not setting used = size fixed the problem. Thank you, Veritas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `resize` function increases `used`. When you access `arr[used+1]` in `push_back`, than you access an invalid array location.

You should add another function, which is similar to `resize`, but changes only the capacity of your array and not the stored object count. (i.e. it does not increment `used`). This function should be called by `push_back`. (As you mentioned `std::vector` in your question, see the difference between [vector::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) and [vector::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/).)

Also: array indexes are zero-based. Do not insert at position `used + 1` but on position `used`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use next implementation. I assume that "cap" member is for capacity of vector and "used" is for amount of elements in array.

```
template <class T>
void darray<T>::resize(unsigned size)
{
  if (size > cap)
  {
    cap = size * 2;
    T* temp_arr = new T[cap];

    for (int count = 0; count < used; ++count)
        temp_arr[count] = arr[count];

    delete [] arr;
    arr = temp_arr;
  }   

  // zero members if size was decreased
  if (size < used)
  {  
     for (int count = size; count < used; ++count)
          arr[count] = T();
  }

  used = size;
}
```

Pros: You don't need to reallocate the whole array each time you do a resize with larger number of elements.

Cons: You spend an extra space when you don't need to.